# Why is the result of CountVectorizer * TfidfVectorizer.idf_ different from TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tfidf

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'docs': ['gamma alfa beta beta epsilon', 'beta gamma eta',], 'labels': ['alfa alfa beta', 'gamma fi']})
```

I use count vectorizer:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer

vocab_docs = set(chain(*[i.split() for i in df['docs'].unique()]))
cv_docs = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab_docs)
cv_docs_s = cv_docs.fit_transform(df['docs'])
```

I do TFIDF:

```
tfidf_docs = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab_docs)
tfidf_docs_s = tfidf_docs.fit_transform(df['docs'])
# tfidf docs
tfidf_docs_s = tfidf_docs_s.todense()
```

but I see that the results are different:

```
test = np.multiply(cv_docs_s.todense(), tfidf_docs.idf_)

test != tfidf_docs_s
```

Why is the result of CountVectorizer * TfidfVectorizer.idf_ different from TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform()?

Answer (score 1):

`TfidfVectorizer` will by default normalize each row. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) we can see that:

> **norm : ‘l1’, ‘l2’ or None, optional (default=’l2’)**
>   Each output row will have unit norm, either: * ‘l2’: Sum of squares of vector elements is 1. The cosine similarity between two vectors is their dot product when l2 norm has been applied. * ‘l1’: Sum of absolute values of vector elements is 1. See preprocessing.normalize

Setting `norm` to `None` will give the result you expect:

```
tfidf_docs = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab_docs, norm=None)
```